# How does keyboard or other I/O devices work before operaing system boots?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

How does keyboard and other I/O devices work before booting of OS.For example: when i have to choose which OS to boot at grub menu?

Comment: [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS)

Comment: so BIOS contains all device drivers?

Comment: no, not all. "enough" - whatever's necessary to allow the user to interact with the system in a basic way.

Comment: In ye olde days, minicomputers had a microcomputer that served as the boot controller.

Comment: This belongs on Super User, not on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because basic devices like the keyboard can be controlled by the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Before the Operating System is loaded the BIOS is in-charge of controlling the the i/o devices.